# issues in wrapping multimap and structures involved function from C++ to python by swig

Tags: python, c++, structure, swig, multimap

I have an issue in wrapping `multimap` and structures involving functions from C++ to python by swig.
The header is like this:

```
/*example.hpp*/    
typedef struct {
    unsigned x;
    unsigned y;
    unsigned z;
    string  accession;
    unsigned cluster;
    unsigned raw_score;
    unsigned ix;
    unsigned iy;
    bool is_specfic;

} cdsearchinfo;

void foo(string& filename, multimap<unsigned, cdsearchinfo>& cdsearchmap, set<unsigned>& gi_set);
```

How should I write the `.i` file for this?

Comment: Check this out: http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/multimap-td5803.html

Comment: Thanks! i just come across that swig has lib: std_map.i